# Let $X,Y$ be random variables in uniform distribution, $0\leq X\leq 3$,$0\leq Y\leq 4$, the probability of $X\leq Y$

Tags: probability

Let $X,Y$ be random variables in uniform distribution, $0\leq X\leq 3$,$0\leq Y\leq 4$, I want to compute the probability of $X\leq Y$

---

For each $X$, the probability of $X\leq Y$ is $\int_X^4\frac{1}{4}$, so is it that the probability is $\int_0^3\frac{1}{3}dX\int_{X}^{4}\frac{1}{4}dY$?

Comment: Independence? ${}$

Comment: Have $X$ and $Y$ separatly uniform distribution, or has $(X,Y)$ uniform distribution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume here that $X$ and $Y$ are such that $f_{X,Y}=\frac{1}{12}$ serves as PDF on $[0,3]\times[0,4]$. If $X$ and $Y$ are independent then that is the case here.

Prescribe function $g$ on this domain by $(x,y)\mapsto 1$ if $x\leq y$ and $(x,y)\mapsto 0$ otherwise.

Then $g$ is the characteristic function of event $\{X\leq Y\}$, so that:

$$P(X\leq Y)=\int_{0}^{3}\int_{0}^{4}\frac{1}{12}g\left(x,y\right)dydx=\frac{1}{12}\int_{0}^{3}\int_{x}^{4}dydx$$

You can also do it with $\int_{0}^{4}\int_{0}^{3}\frac{1}{12}g\left(x,y\right)dxdy$, but the first method is preferable when it comes to calculating the integral (find out why).

Answer (score 0):

You're off to a good start, but I think your integral should read be $\int_0^3 \frac13 \int_X^4 \frac14  dydx$.  (You can't factor $dX$ through the $Y$ integral because of the $X$ in the limit of integration.)

Another approach is to conceptualize this problem as taking a point uniformly at random from the rectangle $[0,3]\times [0,4]$.  You determine where in the rectangle $X\le Y$, and then you can determine what proportion of the area is in this event, which in turn allows you to find the probability.